# How to inherit from a class than inherits from a class generated by a template class and change the template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a design question. I have a class G that inherits from a class Base that was generated using the template class Base and the class Z :

```
class G : public Base<Z>
```

Now I want to create a new class G2 which is the same as G but possesses some more methods. Those methods depend on attributes and methods of a class Z2 that inherits from Z. Basically, I want to add some methods to both G2 and Z2, but not to G or Z.

For now the only idea I have on how to solve this is to template the class G. I feel like, since Z2 inherits from Z, there should be a more clever way to do it.

Is there any way to implement this without templating the class G, or copy pasting code around ?

Comment: Your terminology appears to be wrong. Nothing that's described in your question is actually "specialization", as it's commonly known and used with C++ templates. It goes without saying that everyone needs to be using the same vocabulary, in order to get a meaningful answer to a question. Please rephrase your question using correct terminology. If you are actually specializing something, summarize how it's specialized. Otherwise use the correct terms -- inheritance, instantiation, etc... -- where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing private inheritance of G2 on G and make public all functions of G with `using`. All function of `Base<Z>` will be hidden, since it's private. Inherit over `Base<Z2>` and you get what you wanted. Only thing is that you have both attributes of `Base<Z>` and `Base<Z2>`, (`int x` in example), so object is bigger, so if it is a problem you should make all `Base<T>` inherit from `TrueBase` class and use virtual inheritance. (2nd snipped)

```
template<class T> class Base
{
    int x;
    T* t;
};

class Z
{
    void zfoo() {}
};

class G : public Base<Z>
{
public:
    void foo1() {}
};

class Z2 : public Z
{
    void zfoo2() {}
};

class G2 : private G, public Base<Z2>
{
public:
    using G::foo1;
    void newfoo() {}
};
```

Virtual inheritance, there is only one `int x` in final G2

```
class TrueBase {
public:
    int x;
};
class A :public std::exception
{
public: 
};

template<class T> class Base : virtual public TrueBase
{
public:
    T* t;
};

class Z
{
    void zfoo() {}
};
class G : virtual public Base<Z>
{
public:
    void foo1() {}
};
class Z2 : public Z
{
    void zfoo2() {}
};

class G2 : private G, virtual public Base<Z2>
{
public:
    using G::foo1;

    void newfoo() {}
};
```